# getting error in userQuestion and userAnswer

Tags: flutter, dart, calculator

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GYYTQcohNwA making calculator from this video and getting error on userQuestion and userAnswer. I have followed it properly and tried so hard to fix this issue but still not getting any way to resolve this issue. Please help!! line no. 18 and 26 where the issue is.

What is Dart?
Google had its first ever release of Flutter 1.0 last December, after having it in beta mode for over 18 months. Dart is the programming language used to code Flutter apps. Dart is another product by Google and released version 2.1, before Flutter, in November. As it is starting out, the Flutter community is not as extensive as ReactNative, Ionic, or Xamarin.

A while back, I discovered a liking for JavaScript. I was ecstatic to be working on a ReactNative mobile app for my internship. I enjoy coding hybrid mobile apps too, so wanted to give Flutter a try, as I had done Xamarin sometime last year.

At my first glance of Flutter (and Dart), I felt befuddled and couldn’t seem to understand anything. They even had a section on their docs for developers moving from React Native. So, I took to digging deeper on all things Dart.

Dart looks a bit like C and is an object-oriented programming language. So, if you prefer the C languages or Java, Dart is the one for you, and you’ll likely be proficient in it.

Dart is not only used for mobile app development but is a programming language. Approved as a standard by Ecma (ECMA-408), it’s used to build just about anything on the web, servers, desktop and of course, mobile applications (Yes, the same people who standardized our favorites ES5 and ES6.)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'buttons.dart';
import 'package:math_expressions/math_expressions.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

bool isOperator(String x) {
  if (x == '%' || x == '/' || x == 'x' || x == '+' || x == '-' || x == '=') {
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

void equalPressed() {
  String finalQuestion = userQuestion;
  finalQuestion = finalQuestion.replaceAll('x', '*');

  Parser p = Parser();
  Expression exp = p.parse(finalQuestion);
  ContextModel cm = ContextModel();
  double eval = exp.evaluate(EvaluationType.REAL, cm);

 userAnswer = eval.toString();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  var userQuestion = '';
  var userAnswer = '';

  final List<String> buttons = [
    'C',
    'DEL',
    '%',
    '/',
    '7',
    '8',
    '9',
    'x',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '-',
    '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '+',
    '0',
    '00',
    '.',
    '=',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFFE5CCFF),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 50,
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                      child: Text(
                        userQuestion,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                      child: Text(
                        userAnswer,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Container(
              child: GridView.builder(
                  itemCount: buttons.length,
                  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 4),
                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                    // clear button
                    if (index == 0) {
                      return MyButton(
                        buttonTapped: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userQuestion = '';
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.green,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      );
                    } else if (index == 1) {
                      // Delete Button
                      return MyButton(
                        buttonTapped: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userQuestion = userQuestion.substring(
                                0, userQuestion.length-1);
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.red,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      );
                    }
                    // equal button
                    else if (index == buttons.length-1) {
                      return MyButton(
                        buttonTapped: () {
                          setState(() {
                            equalPressed();
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: Colors.deepPurple,
                        textColor: Colors.white,
                      );
                    } else {
                      // Rest of the Button
                      return MyButton(
                        buttonTapped: () {
                          setState(() {
                            userQuestion += buttons[index];
                          });
                        },
                        buttonText: buttons[index],
                        color: isOperator(buttons[index])
                            ? Colors.deepPurple
                            : Colors.deepPurple[50],
                        textColor: isOperator(buttons[index])
                            ? Colors.white
                            : Colors.deepPurple,
                      );
                    }
                  }),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the methods `isOperator` and `equalPressed` inside your _HomePageState